# google maps in fragment android

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I'm having problems loading a google Maps in my fragment. Everything starts in a recycler  view adapter that launchs  the activity "ViatgeDetallViewActivity" :

```
Context context = mActivity.getApplicationContext(); 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViatgeDetallViewActivity.class);
                   holder.mViatge.getId());
                    intent.putExtra("desc",p.getDesc());
                    intent.putExtra("location",p.getLocation());
                    mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,ACTIVITY_View);
```

This is my DetallViewActivity :

```
public class ViatgeDetallViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViatgeDetallViewFragment fragment;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {

        String s =  getIntent().getStringExtra("desc");
        Location l = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("location");

        Log.d("myTag", "estoy en el oncreate de detallviewActivity pasando pro extras" + s );


    }

        fragment = new ViatgeDetallViewFragment();


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.activity_fragment_view, fragment)  
                .commit();
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_fragment_view, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

With my ViatgeDetallViewFragment being :

```
public class ViatgeDetallViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Marker mMarcadorActual;

public ViatgeDetallViewFragment() {
}
....
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment)
                    getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_view_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


   //ask for permissions..
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMarcadorActual = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));

}
```

With the layouts being , Activity_view:

```
<Linear ...

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tlbMenuView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

fragment_view:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_view" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
..
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_view_map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"></fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem comes when i try launch tje "ViatgeDetallActivity" , i get this in the log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.usuari.myapplication3, PID: 6390
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.usuari.myapplication3/com.example.usuari.myapplication3.ViatgeDetallViewActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.usuari.myapplication3.ViatgeDetallViewFragment.onCreateView(ViatgeDetallViewFragment.java:82)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>   03-24 02:55:53.871 6390-7362/com.example.usuari.myapplication3
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found. 03-24
>   02:55:53.881 6390-7362/com.example.usuari.myapplication3
>   I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2 03-24 02:55:53.881
>   6390-7362/com.example.usuari.myapplication3 I/DynamiteModule: Selected
>   remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version
>
> > = 2 03-24 02:55:53.881 6390-7362/com.example.usuari.myapplication3 W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources:
> >     /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000005/DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk
> >     / 1.0 running in com.example.usuari.myapplication3 rsrc of package
> >     com.example.usuari.myapplication3 03-24 02:55:53.891
> >     6390-7362/com.example.usuari.myapplication3 D/ResourcesManager: For
> >     user 0 new overlays fetched Null 03-24 02:55:53.891
> >     6390-7362/com.example.usuari.myapplication3 W/ResourcesManager:
> >     getTopLevelResources:
> >     /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000005/DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk
> >     / 1.0 running in com.example.usuari.myapplication3 rsrc of package
> >     com.example.usuari.myapplication3

Comment: If I understood correctly, you would like me to change the element fragment in the layout for a SupportMapFragment, but android studio it's not recognising that as a valid type!

Comment: Latest update of Google for Maps, only MapView is supported for fragments. <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" /> [For more Info clink here](http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2017/11/how-to-use-google-map-in-fragment.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `mapFragment` is null. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_view_map);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if the above solution does not work, try this.
Add this in your map fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment map = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }
```

And then add this in your calling activity.
because add method was not working so i tried replace method and it works seemlessly.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);


fragment = new MapsActivity();
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.activity_fragment_view, fragment);
ft.commit();
```